# Grails & Spring Security - Extra authentication filter

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

With Grails ans SS, I need to check data from the DB if a user can or cannot login. 
I tried preAuthenticationChecks and post* but the hibernate session is not yet initialized.
I tried a extra filter in the filterChain extending OncePerRequestFilter but when I throw an AccessDeniedException or a extended AuthenticationException, I got an infinite redirect loop to login/denied.

Any clue on how I could do that?

Thanks in advance

Antoine

Comment: Sounds like the infinite loop might be caused because filter is not excluding the /login requests.  Could you elaborate on what information you are checking in the database?

Comment: I'd like to check if there is an association from an other table to the user table...

Comment: Is the association required for authentication?  e.g. If department includes user, then let them in.

Comment: Yeah something like that...